# Why is query string not making it through to ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET web application that processes query parameters. For some reason, on my current dev machine, by the time the URL gets to .NET, the query string is not present. Unlike similar problems I've googled, even my RawUrl request property does not contain the query string.

I know the app itself works because the exact same app works fine on two other Windows machines. There must be something about the Windows or IIS configuration that is stripping query parameters. I suspect the URL rewrite module which I recently installed (but is also installed on the working machines) but I haven't been able to find the cause.

Comment: just check this setting `On the Start screen, move the pointer all the way to the lower left corner, right-click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.
Expand Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, expand Security, and then select Request Filtering.`

Comment: in short `windows features --> IIS -->worldwidewebservices -->security --> Requestfiltering`  make sure that requestfiltering is checked

Comment: @Webruster it is checked.